# How do I prevent Mobile Safari from accessing the network for a cached webapp?

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile-safari

I have a simple web app that I want to use locally (i.e. I don't want it to ever access the network). All the code is packaged according to the Safari Web Content Guide. I was successful in downloading my web app to my iPhone. I noticed, though, that even though my web app doesn't connect to anything remotely, there will be a network access (the network access indicator fires).

I suspect that iOS is checking to see if the web app is fresh (i.e. checking the cache manifest to see if it needs to update any files). Is there a way to prevent this? It really screws up the user experience.

Answer (score 2):

The never-ending network spinner is a bug in iOS; you won't be able to get around it with a web app:

http://www.devthought.com/2012/09/22/understanding-the-ios6-ajax-bugs/

Comment: It's not a never-ending network spinner. It just spins for about half a second and then an alert comes up saying that I should 'Turn Off  Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data'.